# Merging several xml file and inserting elements at once to output updated xml using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have several xml files as follow:

file : 1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val1</info1>
           <info2>val2</info2>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val3</info1>
           <info2>val4</info2>
       </info>
   </config>
```

file : 2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val5</info1>
           <info2>val6</info2>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val7</info1>
           <info2>val8</info2>
       </info>
   </config>
```

file: 3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val9</info1>
           <info2>val10</info2>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val11</info1>
           <info2>val12</info2>
       </info>
   </config>
```

I would like to merge them and also add to each  node:

```
<info3>XXX</info3>
```

the output should look like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val1</info1>
           <info2>val2</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val3</info1>
           <info2>val4</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val5</info1>
           <info2>val6</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val7</info1>
           <info2>val8</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val9</info1>
           <info2>val10</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val11</info1>
           <info2>val12</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
       </info>
   </config>
```

So far I have been able to merge the file by creating an xml file that list the file I want to merge (merge.xml):

```
<mergeData newRoot="config">
   <filelist>
       <fileItem>1.xml</fileItem>
       <fileItem>2.xml</fileItem>
       <fileItem>3.xml</fileItem>
   </filelist>
</mergeData>
```

using the following xsl (merge.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:element name="{mergeData/@newRoot}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="mergeData/fileList/fileItem"/>
       </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="fileItem">   
       <xsl:copy-of select="document(.)/config/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But how should I modify the xsl to add "info3" into each info at the same time.
"info3" is always the same info for each node.

Can someone help, please?

Note: Next question will be how to generate merge.xml using xml file located into a specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param  name="new">
    <info3>XXX</info3>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:element name="{mergeData/@newRoot}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="document(mergeData/fileList/fileItem)/config/*"/>
       </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="config/*">   
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>
       </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this was not in my initial question, but I finally also need it: add an element after <info3> which is <file>filename</file>. filename been the value in the merge.xml in the fileItem.

Comment: if in my xml file that contains the list of xml file, I want to filter some of them in order to not merge them based on the filename. any idea? thanks

Comment: If you can´t figure it out yourself then consider to ask a new question with the type of file names you have and the kind of filters you want to set up. XSLT 1.0 is not that good on string or file name processing but you can certainly use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="document(mergeData/fileList/fileItem[starts-with(., 'A')])/config/*"/>` on the `fileItem` element.